# Error upgrading spring boot version to 2.6.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, dependency-management

I am upgrading my spring boot application to latest stable version 2.6.6, The Build is successful, but getting below errors on runtime. How can i look why this class PropertySourceLocator is missing, and what steps can someone generally take to solve such issues related to dependencies like in my case. I have tried various things like excluding any conflicting dependencies, using compatible versions of different libraries like spring-boot and spring cloud.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [MainApplicationClass]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/bootstrap/config/PropertySourceLocator.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at MainApplicationClass.main(MainApplicationClass.java:23) [classes/:?]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/bootstrap/config/PropertySourceLocator.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:199) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:55) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:696) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1024) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:386) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:332) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:304) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: can you share pom.xml file? or use Spring initialiser for dependency management https://start.spring.io/

Comment: Please add your `pom.xml`. These errors come from messy dependencies (or trying to outsmart the Dependency management done by Spring Boot itself). The class it complains about is from Spring Cloud, so if you have (indirect) Spring Cloud dependencies you need to upgrade those as well. Spring Cloud versions are strictly tied to certain Spring Boot versions and in this case those are incompatible.

Comment: Yes @M. Deinum thanks, actually there were some transitive cloud dependencies which caused this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have dependency for that class?

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-context -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This isn't an answer but rather a comment.

Comment: Thanks @zawarudo. This worked for me. I had to exclude few of my organisations dependencies and add this cloud-context dependency and it worked for me.

Comment: I had a similar issue when we were migrating microservice from JDK8 to JDK11, and we had some company "bundle" of dependencies, they even bundled spring dependencies, and when I tried to pull all of that, spring-core jar went down to version 4, it was a complete mess, so I feel your pain. Glad you fixed it bro.